# Loading contents HTML from UIWebview iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am loading contents of HTML from `UIWebview` using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` .Issue faced is while loading content from search engine of google website.For example I am searching 'bottle' in google website loaded in `UIWebview`  it gives me the content of HTML of the bottles first time loaded, again I will go to fetch the HTML content when user scrolls down in `UIWebview`, There is a brief pause after calling the javascript causing other elements on the screen to hiccup for a moment.

Placing the javascript call in a function called in the background with self `performSelectorInBackground` breaks the application. Is there a safe way to call run this on a background thread or otherwise prevent the interface from pausing?

Answer (score 0):

The "hiccup" is being caused because `UIWebView`'s `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` is running on the same thread, so it's blocking the UI.

Use `WKWebView` instead. It allows you to call `evaluateJavaScript`, where you provide a completion handler so that the JS call will be done on a separate thread and call the completion handler when it's ready, thus avoiding the "hiccup".